# UITableView cell alignment right not aligning to full right of screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, background-image

I am trying to set the background of a label to be an image, but it is not working, any ideas how to?

Here is the code:

```
cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "chatCellMe.png"))
```

Yes, it is the label of the cell of a tableview. I do not want to set the background image of the cell itself as then it stretches. If I set it of the label, will it also stretch or will it cover only the text inside of it?

Comment: What exactly do you see? Describe the results, and what you want to see instead. Are you using a default UITableViewCell or a subclass?

Comment: If I add a large image to the label of a default cell, that image covers the entire background of the cell, minus a  bit of padding on the left and right sides (if the image is smaller than that, then it gets tiled). Is it this padding you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: No, I am trying to cover just the amount of text in the cell, not the entire cell.

Comment: Then you need to add your own label, size it how you want, and give that label the text and background image. Either create a subclassed cell to do this, or add the label to the default cell (change its type to custom), and access the label using viewWithTag:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use standard `textLabel` property of `UITableViewCell`. Then it always has frame that fits the text.

What behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the background of the label to be a picture

Comment: This is not true. If you add a background color to the textLabel of a default cell, you will see that the label is as large as the cell minus a little padding (~15 points) on the left and right edges.